# "undefined method `build' for Model(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime):Class "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create the functionality
1) User enters first name, last name into a form
2) The form is submitted
3) The show view is loaded, and certain parts of the text are replaced by the parameters
4) If the form is invalid, i.e first name presence is not true, then an error is displayed

---

I've managed to create the functionality for steps 1-3. When a person enters details into a form, it transfers over to a different view. Now, what I would like to do is to validate certain parts of the form.

None of this information is being saved in a database, but I remember that I could use Models to validate forms.

What I tried to do is to create a Model, add an attr_accessor, and validations to it. When the form POSTs, it would build a varaible inside the create action, and I could do an if/than statement.

When I tried this though, I got the error:

```
NoMethodError in ContentController#create

undefined method `build' for Content(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime):Class
```

Here's what my Content#create looks like

```
def create
    @content = Content.build(:params)
    if @content.valid?
        render 'content/show'
    else
        render 'content/new'
    end

end
```

This is the view with the form :

```
<%= form_tag("/content", :method => "post", :id => "form" ) do %>

      <h4>The Doctor's Name</h2>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
      <%= label_tag(:first_name, "First Name") %>
      <%= text_field_tag :first_name, nil, placeholder: "ex: James" %>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
      <%= label_tag(:last_name, "Last Name") %>
      <%= text_field_tag :last_name, nil, placeholder: "ex: Bond" %>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
      <%= label_tag(:full_name, "Full Name") %>
      <%= text_field_tag :full_name, nil, placeholder: "ex: James Bond" %>
      </div>

  </div><!--form_item row-->
  <div class="form_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-block">
        Enter's The Doctor's First Name, Last Name, And Than The Full Name. Do NOT include "Dr."
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pagination-centered">
  <%= submit_tag( raw("Generate The Content!"), :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :style => "font-weight:bold") %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

This is what my model looks like :

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :full_name
    attr_accessor :first_name
    attr_accessor :last_name
    attr_accessor :full_name

    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :full_name, presence: true

end
```

Am I on the right track at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase I was looking for that solved my problem was "tabless models".

This tutorial shows you how to do it -- http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Instead of using form_tag, you can now use form_for, this is how my model ended up looking like :

```
class Content
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :full_name

    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :full_name, presence: true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```